# Grafana SSO login

Tags: single-sign-on, grafana

We are facing issue while configuring the Grafana SSO .

Currently we had configured  it with using Azure AD .

All the active directory level configuration and user  are already added  but it is authenticated everyone  with SSO with defined domain who has that email id .

I need to know is there is any Grafana level configuration we need to add in value.yaml

We had tried to check Azure level and grafana level configuration all looks fine . Below are the details

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/
we have also tried with adding group id  created in Azure AD but still it is failing
Below is configuration file added in prometheus Helm charts

```
name = Azure AD
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
auto_login = false
client_id = APPLICATION_ID
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
scopes = openid email profile
auth_url = 
token_url = 
allowed_domains = lntinfotech .com 
allowed_groups =
```

Azure AD level changes  snippet

[Azure AD snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Hj6.png)
[Azure AD snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAY0s.png)

Ideally it should only authenticate  only those people who has  been added in that group with SSO not all who has domain access .
Kindly let me if any one has any solution around on the same.

Answer (score 0):

We have AzureAD oauth enabled on Grafana and access within the organization is limited to specific AD security groups. To grant access to Grafana, set the object ID of the relevant AD group as shown below in your `grafana.ini`.

`allowed_groups: "<group1_object_id>", "<group2_object_id>"`

This configuration permits only users within the specified group, while others encounter an error. To enable access for multiple groups, separate the object IDs with commas, utilizing Azure AD object IDs. Additionally, you can manage access levels for each AD security group using app roles.
Any other user that's not part of the allowed groups will see the below error:

`Login failed user not a member of one of the required groups`